# toolchain parameter in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-17

My question is about `toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))` parameter in gradle.

I have java project written in Java 8 and built using gradle 6.7:

```
cat build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.25.0'
}
```

I have upgraded java 8 to java 17 by adding `toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))` parameter to `build.gradle`.
This update forced me to upgrade gradle from 6.7 to 8.1.1, as well as update the version of one of the plugins. Putting all together, `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.35.0' //update version from 0.25.0 to 0.35.0
}


java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

The `toolchain` parameter tells gradle to use java 17 for running gradle-tasks, as well as to set source compatibility and target compatibility parameters.

When I have java 17 installed on my local machine - the build is successful, but if I use java 8, then I get an error:
"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/palantir/gradle/docker/DockerComponent has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"

It's wrong behaviour, because the `toolchain` config should resolve this problem.

How can I fix this?

P.S.
There is the same question of gradle site but without an answer:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/specifying-gradle-version-and-java-toolchain-version-isnt-enough/41111

Also I have read an article about `toolchain` parameter:
https://stefma.medium.com/sourcecompatibility-targetcompatibility-and-jvm-toolchains-in-gradle-explained-d2c17c8cff7c

There are 3 interesting paragraphs there:

> With this setup, it “no longer matters” which JDK version you use to
> run Gradle (tasks). You can even use your locally installed JDK in
> version 8. Gradle will detect that it should use a JDK in version 17
> to build (compile, test, etc.), so it will download it for you and
> store it in ~/.gradle/jdks for later reuse.
>
> The attentive reader may notice the double quotes I put around no
> longer matters, in the section above. This is intentional, because the
> catch to all of this, is that it does matter which JDK you have
> installed locally (and on the continuous integration server machine)
> to run Gradle (tasks).
>
> As mentioned at the beginning of this blog, AGP 8.0 requires Java 17.
> And that is what it means. This doesn’t mean that the source code or
> target (bytecode) needs to be written in version 17, it means that the
> AGP itself requires Java 17, since it is compiled with a JDK in
> version 17, or at least targetCompatibility is set to version 17.

But I didn't understand them because they condratict each other

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> com/palantir/gradle/docker/DockerComponent has been compiled by a more
> recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this
> version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to
> 52.0

> The toolchain parameter tells gradle to use java 17 for running gradle-tasks, as well as to set source compatibility and target compatibility parameters.

When building Java projects, there are multiple instances of JVMs running.

The first JVM process is Gradle itself. Gradle is a Java program, and therefore needs a JVM instance to execute in. This is whatever version you have installed globally on your machine.

Next, for any compilation, running, or testing of your own Java project, Gradle spins up a new JVM process for each of those. This JVM process does not need to be the same JVM version that the Gradle process itself is running with. That is where the toolchain comes it. It is only for the child processes that are spawned when Gradle needs to run, for example, compilation or tests. Gradle will download a JDK via the toolchain functionality only for those child JVM processes that are used for working with your own Java code.

Gradle will not download its own JDK to execute itself in because it needs a pre-installed JDK in order to parse its own files and download the toolchain JDK.

The error you are getting is because you need to have at least JDK 11 to use that particular version of the `com.palantir.docker` plugin (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2), but lets say that you have JDK 11 pre-installed on your system. Here would be the sequence of events:

1. You execute the Gradle command: `gradle compileJava`
2. JVM 11 process spins up on your machine running Gradle
3. Gradle parses its own files, downloads the plugin JARs, and executes the
   plugins
4. Gradle looks at toolchain settings and checks to see if you have version JDK 17 installed already on your system
5. If not, Gradle downloads a version JDK 17
6. Gradle (JVM 11 process) spawns a child Java compile process (via the
   `compileJava` task) from the JDK 17 that it downloaded
7. Your code is compiled with the Java 17 compiler
8. The Java 17 compiler exits
9. The compileJava task (in JVM 11 process) finishes
10. The main Gradle program (in JVM 11 process) finishes
11. JVM 11 process exits
12. The command prompt is returned to you

So, in summary, the toolchain has no bearing on the main Gradle process. Gradle will execute the downloaded JDKs from tool chain as child processes.

Comment: so, to run the task `gradle build`, not my local jdk is used, but the one that gradle will download itself based on the toolchain. It should run the `gradle build` command on java17, and it doesn't matter which java I have installed. Why am I still getting the error?

Comment: Your local JVM is used to execute Gradle itself, but then Gradle executes a separate JVM process (the JVM from the toolchain) to run the build.